# Cannot delete my own comment to a locked post

Tags: discussion, bug, support, comments

Let me start by stating that I participate a little bit in this site, in the form of upvoting questions and answers and, as of today, flagging comments.

Earlier today I came across 3 comments from the same user which were in disaccord with a notice from a moderator. One of them did state that this site is actually a discussion forum, and I provided another comment meant to explain that it isn't, along with a link to the [official FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/251162). Aditionally, I flagged these comments for moderation.

Now that they are no longer, I wish to delete my comment, but it's not possible:

[image: red notice - this comment is not eligible for voting or flagging]

and just like the message states, neither me nor anyone can now flag this comment as obsolete.

Is preventing users from deleting their own comments in locked posts a thought-of feature, or is this a "bug"?

Link to question: [Why are terminal consoles still used?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/101990/74435)

Comment: For now I deleted the comment since you wanted it gone (and I see no reason not to), I think the lock feature works like this because it's also used for edit-wars, but I'll leave this as a comment instead of an answer in case someone knows the logic for sure.

Comment: @BenBrocka Appreciate it!